# Spring Security 5 custom authentication fails

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using spring spring security 5.1.4 and i am trying to authenticate user with custom authentication.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

   /* @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
*/
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

and my custom authenticationprovider is

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
      String username = authentication.getName();
      String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        Optional<Tbluser> dbUser = userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName());

        Tbluser dUser = dbUser.get();
        String dbPassword = dUser.getPassword();

        boolean passwordsMatch = passwordEncoder.matches(password,dbPassword);

        if(!passwordsMatch) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password");
        }

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, Collections.emptyList());

    }
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?>aClass) {
        return aClass.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

so whenever i debug the password i provide in seen in the plain text i.e in authentication object but the password i fetch from database is encoded form.

```
 boolean passwordsMatch = passwordEncoder.matches(password,dbPassword);
```

is always false.

how do i authenticate them ?

Comment: Have you debugged and examined the value of `password`? (It may not be what you expect.) Also, is there a specific reason that you're not just using the built-in `DaoAuthenticationProvider` that does exactly this?

Comment: the value of password is whatever i send as request, for e.g if if i request it with {"username":"test","password":"testpass"} it's testpass.

Comment: Try using String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password); and then check if encodedPassword is same as dbPassword or not.

Comment: @sagarlimbu Show your password from request and your encoded password from database.